# The difference between i == 1 or i == 2 and i == (1 or 2) in Python

Tags: python, syntax

**What is (1 or 2) and (1 and 2) mean in Python?**

I was writing python. I'm sick of those repetitive `or` sentences. This is juat an example.

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i == 1 or i == 2:
        print(i)
```

I suddenly thought of novices often make mistakes like `if i == 1 or 2`. It always return `True` because the `2`. Then why not bracket it! So I tried this:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i == (1 or 2):
        print(i)
```

I thought I would get a syntax error, but I got this:

```py
1
```

Why I only got `1`, where was the number `2`?
I changed `(1 or 2)` to `(2 or 1)`, then I got `2` this time. Next I changed it to `(1 and 2)`. I guess it doesn't make sense logically, but it outputed `2`. `and` always outputs the last number, `or` outputs the first one.

```py
>>>print(1 or 2)
1
>>>print(1 and 2)
2
>>>print(1 or 2 or 3)
1
>>>print(1 and 2 and 3)
3
>>>print(1 or 2 and 3)
1
>>>print(1 and 2 or 3)
2
```

So, how did these fantastic results come about? What did they mean?

Comment: `or` only needs one of the terms to be `True`, so it will always return the _first_ `True` element - in your examples it will always return `1`. On the other hand `and` needs all terms to be `True` so it will always return the _last_ one if they are all `True`, or the _first_ `False` one: try `1 and 0 and 2`

Comment: That's called **lazy** condition in Python. In case `a and b`, if a is false, its value is returned. Otherwise, b is evaluated and the value is returned.

In case `a or b`, if a is true, its value is returned. Otherwise, b is evaluated and the value is returned. That's reason why if `i == (1 or 2)` true, it always returns 1.